# Loop through Sortable Row JQuery

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui-sortable

How can I loop or get the data for each row in my table using Sortable JQuery.
The only thing I can do is to get the data after i sort the row but it only return the index of the row which i drag.

## Here is the Code:

```
$('document').ready(function(){
     $('tbody').sortable({
          update: function(event, ui) {
          //i want to do the looping here
          }
     })
});
```

I want to get the data from No. field after loop happen

[image: Table Sort]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OMG I solve my own problem

I loop first the row from the table using each function then i put it in update function of sortable

## Here is the code

```
$('document').ready(function(){
    $('tbody').sortable({
        update: function(event, ui) {
            //loop data

            $('tbody:first th').each(function() {
                var data = $(this).html();
               // alert(data);
            
                //do the saving here
            });
        }

    });
})
```